# Obtaining one column of a RDD[Array[String]] and converting it to dataset/dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a .csv file that I read in to a RDD:

```
val dataH = sc.textFile(filepath).map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim))
```

I would like to iterate over this RDD in order and compare adjacent elements, this comparison is only dependent of one column of the datastructure. It is not possible to iterate over RDDs so instead, the idea is to first convert the column of RDD to either a Dataset or Dataframe.

You can convert a RDD to a dataset like this (which doesn't work if my structure is `RDD[Array[String]]`:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)  
val sqc = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqc.implicits._
val lines = sqc.createDataset(dataH)
```

How do I obtain just the one column that I am interested in from `dataH` and thereafter create a dataset just from it?

I am using Spark 1.6.0.

Comment: which spark version are you using?

Comment: Spark 1.6, forgot to mention it, sorry!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for, can you give an example (input, expected output)?

Comment: I have a .csv file of a couple of columns. I map this to an RDD consistings of Array[String] where each element in the RDD is one row in the csv table. I want to iterate over the table, however since I only need to take one column into consideration I would like to convert one column of a RDD[Array[String]] to a Dataset[String]. (or Dataframe if its easier/better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map your Array to the desired index, e.g. :

```
dataH.map(arr => arr(0)).toDF("col1")
```

Or safer (avoids Exception in case the index is out of bound):

```
dataH.map(arr => arr.lift(0).orElse(None)).toDF("col1")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine! Guess I'll be using a Dataframe instead of Dataset then

Comment: @osk You can also create a Dataset (just use `toDS` instead of `toDF("col1")`), but Datasets are only experimental prior to Spark 2